# Градиент фигуры, состоящей из кривых линий

Tags: javascript, html5

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0,0,50,0);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(5,5,0,50);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0,0,0,-50);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000'; // Цвет обводки
ctx.lineWidth = 3; // Ширина линии
ctx.stroke();
```

Этот код нарисует уголок закруглённый во внутрь (на треугольник смахивает). Как залить этот уголок градиентом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример исходя из написанного на http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-linear-gradients/:

```
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 50, 50);
grd.addColorStop(0, "#8ED6FF"); // light blue
grd.addColorStop(1, "#004CB3"); // dark blue
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fill();
```